# JavaScript/JQuery/JSON Splice Multidimensional Array Clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, splice

I have a JSON object in a file called list.js that looks like this -->

```
var jsonData = [
  {
    name: "Friends",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Steve",
        job: "pro bowler",
        size: "tall",
        description: "Steve's my man!"
      },
      {
        name: "Jessica",
        job: "HR",
        size: "average",
        description: "a dear friend"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Co-Workers",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Martin",
        job: "my boss",
        size: "tall",
        description: "I don't like him"
      },
      {
        name: "Susan",
        job: "Intern",
        size: "average",
        description: "It's not like I have a crush on her or anything..."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I have a webpage that will have data on it that looks like this -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="list.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Name</td><td class="name">Jenkins</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Job</td><td class="job">Accountant</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Size</td><td class="size">Small</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="description">average joe.</td>
            <td>
                <button class="learn">Learn</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".learn").click(function(){


        var data =  {

            // captures the information relevent to the button in a key-value array
            name: $(this).closest("table").find(".name").text(),
            job: $(this).closest("table").find(".job").text(),
            size: $(this).closest("table").find(".size").text(),
            description: $(this).closest("td").siblings(".description").text()
        }

        console.log(data);

        jsonData[0].items.splice(0, 0, {
            name: $(this).closest("table").find(".name").text(),
            job: $(this).closest("table").find(".job").text(),
            size: $(this).closest("table").find(".size").text(),
            description: $(this).closest("td").siblings(".description").text()
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm attempting to use splice() in order to add the data captured by the button click (you can see it in the console afterwards) to the first element of the JSON object's "items" section. I need some help in understanding what I'm doing wrong, any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here your code it's working, you adding the captured data to first element of JSON object in items section, are you sure you are getting access to the JsonData variable in list.js?

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: @DanPhilip I would like to see within list.js that underneath "friends" in the items section there is an element with the information of "jenkins", "accountant", "small", and "average joe."

Answer (score 0):

Saving data to a local JSON file is not possible by pure JavaScript or jQuery alone. You need server side script to do it. Other than that you're code works fine.

Comment: How would I accomplish that?